# Cannot access ApplicationName.Server namespace from Client project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor web application sln which contains Client, Server, and Shared project. I try to access a namespace in Server project from Client project.
[image]

Im trying to access the ApplicationUser.cs . What should I do?

Comment: You're not supposed to.  Both Client and Server should have a reference to Shared, which is where you can put shared classes.  The Client should not hold any references to classes in the Server project as they're deployed in different locations (client web-browser vs server).

Comment: I agree with @NeilW on this. Plus you dont want the details in ApplicationUser as it includes all the properties of IdentityUser (Password hash etc) in the client. Use a DTO and that should be in a slim shared dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create **a .NET Standard library** project in the Shared folder, and **create classes** that need to be used by **Client and Server**. Then you only need to **reference the Shared project** in the **Client project**.